# How to avoid concurrent select queries on azure cosmos container picking same rows

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to run a poller on azure cosmos container which will run at regular intervals and fire a select query something like -:

```
SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c._ts DESC LIMIT 100
```

After selecting the rows, I will do my operations in the application. The problem is that if I need to horizontally scale this poller to lets say 2 instances in future, and both of them run at the same time, how do I prevent them to pick same set of rows?

Also, I am not leveraging change feed processor because for change feed processor to scale horizontally, we need more physical partitions. I need to scale horizontally even within one physical partition.

I can implement optimistic locking but I do not want to select and then reject rows. Is there any way to pick different set of rows while select operation itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a single process read the data and distribute the rows over a horizontal scalable processor. That single process could be a timer triggered Azure Function with a [cosmos db input binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp) or your own application. My point is: you should not scale the poller but the processing.

Some options:

- Put each row on a queue and use a queue triggered azure function
- Create an http request with row data  and post it to an http triggered azure function or any suitable endpoint (could be your own application if that can scale to multiple instances)
- Send the rows to an Azure Event Hub and setup some processing logic

Comment: thanks for the reply. This is also a good way of approaching the problem. Instead of scaling the poller, we can indeed scale the processing.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is scaling the Change Feed of Cosmos DB, then rather than building something custom or polling that will consume RUs and need a timer infrastructure, why don't you listen to Change Feed and add that as Message into Service Bus or Event Grid Topic. Then have another Azure Function or Logic App or your preferred compute listen to Service Bus Queue and Process the messages.

Also, you can have different partition schema than your Cosmos in Service Bus Queue that will allow you to run Multiple Brokers. Also, you can create different Subscriptions in Event Grid Topic or use Topics in Service Bus to create a Priority Queue and process certain changes on high priority, if your application demands it.